# Pandas.dropna method can't delete Nan value rows(or columns)

Tags: pandas

I now have some data, it's may contain null values

I want to delete it's null value (a whole row or a whole column)

How can I deal with the comparison?

Here is my data

https://reurl.cc/5lONv6

it will have some null values ​​in the time series data

following is my code

```
c=pd.read_csv('./in/historical_01A190.txt',error_bad_lines=False)
c.dropna(axis=0,how='any',inplace=True)
c.dropna(axis=1,how='any',inplace=True)
c.to_csv('./out/historical_01A190.txt',index=False)
```

but it's didn't work

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first of all, your data isn't saved as a csv.  It's saved as a tab-separated file.

So you need to open it using pd.read_table

```
>>> c=pd.read_table('./data.txt',error_bad_lines=False,sep='\t')
```

Second, your data is full of nans -- if you use dropna on either rows or columns, you end up with just one row or column (dates) left. But using the correct opener on your file, the dropna and to_csv functions work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't assing the variable then it will only create a view which is not stored in memory.

```
c = c.dropna(axis=0,how='any',inplace=True)
c = c.dropna(axis=1,how='any',inplace=True)
c = c.to_csv('./out/historical_01A190.txt',index=False)
```

Try this.